# Video not playing in Firefox on Mac

Tags: macos, video, firefox, web-browsing

When I open this link [Erlang](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/joe-armstrong-erlang-qcon08) which has a video, the video won't play. I am a beginner to Mac and recently reinstalled my macOS. I dont know why this video won't play on my Mac, but the same video plays in Firefox on another Linux based machine.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is a flash video. You need to install flash for firefox.  https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: In addition to the answer by בנימן הגלילי, I just wanted to add I couldn't get it to play in Safari, Firefox or Chrome in either macOS or Windows, so this behaviour isn't unique to OS or browser.